# Edit/show Primary Key in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

It appears Django hides fields that are flagged Primary Key from being displayed/edited in the Django admin interface.

Let's say I'd like to input data in which I may or may not want to specify a primary key.  How would I go about displaying primary keys in the admin interface, and how could I make specifying it optional?

Comment: Why would you want to be able to edit the primary key? Do any other models reference the primary key of the model whose primary key you want to edit?

Comment: In some cases, the primary key has already been specified.  A lot of the data I'm dealing with is shared via XML or JSON, used in a production environment (so I can't just change things), and I would like to get by without the slop of an optional look-up field.  I'd rather just accept the current keys and fill in around it.

While I can do this easily on the back-end, filling in a little test data sucks if I can't tweak the pk for testing.

Perhaps you have a better way, though.  I'm probably gonna have to just go for using a provider_id field.

Answer (score 38):

I also wanted to simply show the 'id' (primary key) within the Django admin, but not necessarily edit it. I just added it to the `readonly_fields` list, and it showed up fine. IE:

```
class StudentEnrollmentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Enrollment
    readonly_fields=('id',)
```

whereas if I tried to add it to the 'fields' list, Django got upset with me, saying that field didn't exist...

Comment: Yup. Django hides them from editing as edits have undefined semantcis

Answer (score 15):

If you explicitly specify the primary key field in your models (with `primary_key=True`), you should be able to edit it in the admin.

For Django models created via `./manage.py syncdb` the following primary key field is added automatically:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

if you change (or add) that to your model explicitly as an IntegerField primary key, you'll be able to edit it directly using the admin:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

But as others pointed out, this is a potential minefield...

Comment: You are certainly right.  I opted for an extra field that's optional and prefacing every regular check with a call for that key.  I suppose Django filters either any AutoKey fields or just filters out keys named id.

Kind of disappointing that it won't let me force bad practices upon it.

Comment: Yes it seems that it filters AutoField's which makes sense. But if you specify it as an IntegerField you'll be able to edit it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

To show the primary key, which by default will have a column name of "id" in the database - use "pk"

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {} ({})'.format(self.pk, self.name, self.pcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have an optional primary key. Either the PK is an autoincrement, in which case there's no need to edit it, or it's manually specified, in which case it is always required.

Why do you need this?

Comment: I commented above on my reasoning, and it's starting to look like a bad idea.

Really though, how can I edit primary keys in django's admin.  Let's say I'm masochistic.

Answer (score 1):

In [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields), there is a short sentence about that, which is not clear:

> If neither fields nor fieldsets options are present, Django will default to displaying each field that isn't an AutoField and has editable=True, in a single fieldset, in the same order as the fields are defined in the model.

Reason is, django do not allow you to edit an `AutoField` by any means (and that is the right thing since it is an auto increment value and should not be edited). @mnelson4's answer is a good approach to display it.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer with the highest votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279773/59439) didn't work for me.  I needed a getter.

```
class StudentEnrollmentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Enrollment
    readonly_fields=('student_enrollment_id',)

    def student_enrollment_id(self, obj):
        return obj.id
```

Using django 1.11