# How to make an auto-filled and auto-incrementing field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, default-value

[**Update:** Changed question title to be more specific]

Sorry if I didn't make the question very well, I can't figure how to do this:

```
class WhatEver():
    number = model.IntegerField('Just a Field', default=callablefunction)
...
```

Where `callablefunction` does this query:

```
from myproject.app.models import WhatEver

def callablefunction():
    no = WhatEver.objects.count()
    return no + 1
```

I want to automatically write the next number, and I don't know how to do it.

I have errors from `callablefunction` stating that it cannot import the model, and I think there must be an easier way to do this. There's no need even to use this, but I can't figure how to do it with the pk number.

I've googled about this and the only thing I found was to use the save() method for auto incrementing the number... but I wanted to show it in the `<textfield>` before saving...

What would you do?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Got it!** I hope this will help everyone that has any problems making a auto-filled and auto-incrementing field in django. The solution is:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    """This is the client data model, it holds all client information. This
       docstring has to be improved."""
    def number():
        no = Cliente.objects.count()
        if no == None:
            return 1
        else:
            return no + 1

    clientcode = models.IntegerField(_('Code'), max_length=6, unique=True, \
    default=number)

    [... here goes the rest of your model ...]
```

Take in care:

- The `number` function doesn't take any arguments (not even self)
- It's written **BEFORE** everything in the model
- This was tested on django 1.2.1

This function will automatically fill the `clientcode` field with the next number (i.e. If you have 132 clients, when you add the next one the field will be filled with `clientcode` number 133)

I know that this is absurd for most of the practical situations, since the PK number is also auto-incrementing, but there's no way to autofill or take a practical use for it inside the django admin.

[update: as I stated in my comment, there's a way to use the primary key for this, but it will not fill the field **before** saving]

Comment: Are you sure this code will also work with concurrent transactions? What happens when two requests both do a `count()` at the same time, and write the same value later?

Comment: That's true... in my use case it doesn't matter because there will never be two requests at a time... but even then I must think a better way to implement this. Thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: I've been able to perform something similar to what I want making this field: `id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)` The only thing is that it's not auto filled, but solves the problem of simultaneous requests (I think)

Comment: You can never delete anything from this table, right? Otherwise you'll get duplicate codes.

Comment: Consider using `Cliente.objects.aggregate(Max('clientcode'))` instead of `Cliente.objects.count()`. This way you will avoid duplicate value problem.

Comment: Also consider using `select_for_update` to prevent errors with concurrent requests.

Answer (score 8):

Every Django model already has an [auto-generated primary key](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id1):

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

It seems you are trying to duplicate an already existing behavior, just use the object primary key.

Comment: I know about primary keys, but I have to show that number inside the django admin page. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531762/edit-show-primary-key-in-django-admin

Comment: That does not work. If you put it as an AutoField django crashes. And if its an IntegerField it does not work as expected. It just becomes a normal IntegerField. I need that field to be auto filled with the next number (I think i'm very bad explaining myself)

Comment: If you must, just add another field which is an `AutoField`, but not a primary key. In any case, sounds like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You cannot have AutoField without primary_key=True flag in you model.

Answer (score 6):

I, too, came across this problem, my instance of it was `customer.number` which was relative to the customers `Store`. I was tempted to use something like:

```
# Don't do this:

class Customer(models.Model):
    # store = ...
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.number == 0:
            try:
                self.number = self.store.customer_set.count() + 1
            else:
                self.number = 1
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**The above can cause several problems:** Say there were 10 Customers, and I deleted customer number 6. The next customer to be added would be (seemingly) the 10th customer, which would then become a second Customer #10. (This could cause big errors in `get()` querysets)

What I ended up with was something like:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    customer_number = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Customer(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.number == 0:
            self.number = self.store.customer_number
            self.store.number += 1
            self.store.save()
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

PS:

You threw out several times that you wanted this field filled in "*before*". I imagine you wanted it filled in before saving so that you can access it. To that I would say: this method allows you to access `store.customer_number` to see the next number to come.

Comment: Even though this will solve the duplicate problem but still voids will be there if I delete a entry in between.Can't be used as index number for tuples in the table.

Comment: Is there any way to generate numbers such that they are continuos and last number's value should equal to `count()`.All numbers should get updated when a entry is deleted?I suppose this can be done delete event detection and using a loop to update all entries.But i don't know how to do this in django models.Can u please edit your code to solve this problem..

Comment: The method I made works like auto increment does, as in, it doesn't reuse numbers. You could write a loop to go and update the numbers, but it probably isnt worth [your] the time to write that function, and not worth the [computer] time to run it. With even a small database, the time to hit all those records could be huge.

Comment: Yes time complexity is an issue..may be that's why auto increment field also have voids if data is deleted!

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in code, that's why you can't import it:

```
from django.db import models
class WhatEver(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField('Just a Field', default=0)
```

and Yuval A is right about auto-incrementing: **you don't even need to declare such a field**. Just use the `pk` or `id`, they mean the same unless there's a composite pk in the model:

```
> w = Whatever(number=10)
> w
<Whatever object>
> w.id
None
> w.save()
> w.id
1
```

[update] Well, I haven't tried a callable as a default. I think if you fix these errors, it must work.

Comment: I think as for django 1.2.1 Field.default() can have a callable object, instead of just a number/string