# Pulling 'id' from sqlite3 into fieldset?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using django and python to create a web app. I have my sqlite3 DB and on the admin class I have:

```
class Job_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['project', 'customer', 'pub_date', 'closed', ('contract','abamount')]}),
        ('Sales', {'fields': ['sales', 'office_choice'], 'classes': ['wide']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('project', 'id', 'sales', 'pub_date')
    search_fields = ['id', 'project']


admin.site.register(New_job, Job_Admin)
```

Now the 'id' is the incremented number the sqlite db gives it. Im also using this as the 'job' number since I need it to increment as well. My issue is that I can use 'id' in the list_display and it works. But I can't put it into the fieldset, it errors out saying "'Job_Admin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' refers to field 'id' that is missing from the form."

Extra: I am curious if I can give it a label/variable name because I will most likely need to pull this data out later too.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Django hides fields which are marked as primary key from the admin interface (which, in SQLite, I believe your id field would be a PK by default), to prevent editing.  This post offers a possible solution by including it in readonly_fields:

[Edit/show Primary Key in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531762/edit-show-primary-key-in-django-admin)