# Django edit databases entrys Primary Key

Tags: python, database, django, primary-key

That's all , i want to know how to do so i can edit the primary keys on my db , I have already tried creating a model.Admin with list_editable and set 'id' but it didnt work

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('article_title','article_body','article_state','id')
list_editable = ('id','article_state',)
```

Ideas ?

Comment: If `id` is an `AutoField`, you would _not_ be able to edit it. However, changing that to `IntegerField` would make it editable - but WHY ? It is quite dangerous to do so.

Comment: Nothing good can come of this

Comment: Yep. Why don't you explain why you want to do this? There's probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: (@Nathaniel There's two kinds of good: Good for nothing and no good. So it sounds like there's plenty of good to be had here.)  These aren't your product item numbers you're updating, are they?

Comment: Changing Primary Keys in a database is a `bad idea`. Even more when you use a ORM. Like advised, use IntegerFields to do what you want to do.

Comment: If your primary keys are keys that will be visible somewhere, they probably shouldn't be primary keys. You may need to re-think why you need to change the primary key.

Comment: Discussed in here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531762/edit-show-primary-key-in-django-admin

Comment: What i want to do is change the order in which they are displayed went i render them on the HTML

Answer (score 0):

To change the order you could add an order field:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Not quite sure you would want to do this but it's at least an option.
        if self.order == 0 and self.pk:
            self.order = self.pk
```